# Why am I not able to, get artifacts present in artifactory repository hosted on cloud , even after successful mount of it using davfs

Tags: artifactory, webdav

I am trying to mount an artifactory repository, which is **hosted on cloud** using davfs (webDav) , but after successful mount, I dont find the artifacts in the mounted directory.

I tried to mount an another **artifactory instance which is not hosted on cloud** , I could successfully mount it and access the artifacts. Does artifactory being on cloud make any difference when we mount ?

Though there are **artifacts present** in https://ARTIFACTORY_ON_CLOUD/repository/   I **dont find** them in the /mountDir even after **successful** mount

CONSOLE OUTPUT :

sudo mount -t davfs https://ARTIFACTORY_ON_CLOUD/repository/ /mountDir/
Please enter the username to authenticate with proxy
www-proxy.us.oracle.com or hit enter for none.
  Username: ******
Please enter the password to authenticate user ****** with proxy
www-proxy.us.oracle.com or hit enter for none.
  Password:
Please enter the username to authenticate with server
https://ARTIFACTORY_ON_CLOUD/repository/ or hit enter for none.
  Username: ******
Please enter the password to authenticate user ******
https://ARTIFACTORY_ON_CLOUD/repository/ or hit enter for none.
  Password:

ls -altr /mountDir/
total 1
drwx------ 2 root root  0 Jun 27 22:49 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 72 Jun 27 22:49 .

what are the possible reasons for not being able to get the artifacts in mountDir